# Make elements fixed when their bottom edge scrolls into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This one might seem complicated, I'll do my best to explain!

I'm trying to make a continuous scrolling article display along the same lines of Bloomberg Politics (http://www.bloomberg.com/politics/articles/2015-07-02/fact-checking-rick-perry-s-economic-speech), but in a slightly different format.

Instead of the next article being static until the last has scrolled away, I would like the current articles bottom edge to become sticky/fixed to the bottom of the viewport and the new article to scroll in over the top of it.

I have attempted a jsfiddle to try and illustrate where I've got to and what I mean.....

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article class="article article--one">
        Text text text text text text text text text
    </article>
    <article class="article article--two">
        Text text text text text text text text text
    </article>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.article {
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
    min-height: 1200px;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 24px;
}

.article--two {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.scroll {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    margin-top: 1248px !important;
    float: left !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}
```

```js
$(window).scroll( function() {    
    $('.article').each( function(i) {    
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var height = $(this).outerHeight();
        var secondheight = $('.article--two').outerHeight();
        var down = bottom_of_object;

        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {     
            $(this).css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '0',
                'left': '16px',
                'right': '16px'
            });
            $('.article--two').addClass('scroll');    
        }    
    });     
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foneqxkf/)

Any help would be gratefully appreciated! Ask away of this seems a little complicated!

Cheer!

Comment: I don't think it will be complicated, I just need to understand what is the thing you want to achieve. You want the next article's title to sit at the bottom of page until you reach it or?

Comment: @Skatch I just want the next article to sit out of sight until the current one has scrolled fully into view. Additionally, the user should be able to scroll back to the top of the first article if they desire.

Comment: I still don't get it... Maybe a picture would explain better, or maybe I just need a second coffee :)

Comment: It is a wee bit early on a Monday to be sure! Essentially I want exactly whats happening in the JsFiddle with the proviso that the user should be able to scroll back to the top of the first article and it should work for an unlimited number of articles in a row.

Comment: OK, I think I am starting to get it. You want article `n` to scroll normally with 16px spacing, you want article `n-1` to be fixed to the bottom, stretched and visible on the left and right side (16px each)? What about article `n-2`?

Comment: The padding doesn't matter so much, it's more the jQuery logic around getting the current article (n) to become fixed by its bottom edge to the bottom of the viewport and allowing the next article (n+1?) to scroll over the top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not optimised, nor will it work fantastic in mobile, but it does the trick.

```js
$window = $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
    
    $('li').each(function (i) {
       var $el = $(this),
           offset = scroll - $el.offset().top - $el.height();
       $el.children().css('top', offset>0 ? offset : 0);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  counter-reset: page;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  height: 150vh;
  list-style: none;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
article {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}
article:before {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: "Page " counter(page);
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <article></article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article></article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article></article>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems pretty solid to me! Thanks for this!